# Massive Download [ETH] smart contracts

Tags: mysql, security, blockchain, ethereum, geth

I'm **looking for the most valid path to download and keep downloading every single smart contract on the ethereum network.**

As I've been programming for a few years, I've been thinking about using cURL to make this. But I'm aware this is probably very outdated as it should be possible to be done somehow using the blockchain...

I'm willing to **store all the contracts in a traditional MySQL database**, in order to run multiple security audits on them. Is there any other database engine compatible with PHP that you would recommend to store them?

How would you approach this?

Answer (score 0):

So far the best approach I've found is to run a fully synchronised node, and then somehow extract all information into bigQuery or something alike... but it seems a little bit hard to accomplish. Any ideas?